# The site is working perfect but I've got an error when I run “bundle exec rake test” -2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an error again that everything is working perfect in localhost but when I run "bundle exec rake test", I have an error.

**Error**

```
$ bundle exec rake test
 1) Error:
  UsersProfileTest#test_profile_display:
  ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `supports' for nil:NilClass
  app/views/shared/_support_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__support_form_html_erb__582342844135452036_70190475648520'
  app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_microposts__micropost_html_erb___1173022564425897832_70190475500520'
  app/views/users/show.html.erb:19:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__2940108544736749993_70190457308940'
  test/integration/users_profile_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:UsersProfileTest>'

 78 runs, 286 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

**support_form.html.erb**

```
 <% if support = current_user.supports.find_by_micropost_id(micropost.id) %>
  <% micropost.supports.each do |support| %>
    <% if current_user?(support.user) %>
      <button class="btn" type="submit">
    <%= link_to "Not Support", [support.micropost, support], method: :delete %>
      </button>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
 <% else %>
 <%= form_for ([micropost, @support]) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :micropost_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>

   <button class="btn" type="submit">
     Support
   </button>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

**supports_controller.rb**

```
 def create
    @support = Support.new(micropost_id: params[:micropost_id], user: current_user)
 if @support.save
     redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  else
     redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end
 end

  def destroy
    @support.destroy
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end
```

**supports_controller_test.rb**

```
 require 'test_helper'

  class SupportsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    def setup
       @user = users(:michael)
       @micropost = microposts(:orange)
       @support = @user.supports.build(micropost_id:@micropost.id)
     end
   end
```

**sessions_helper.rb**

```
 def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
 end

 def current_user
     if (user_id = session[:user_id])
       @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
     elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
     if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
      @current_user = user
     end
  end
 end
```

**user_profile_test.rb**

```
 require 'test_helper'

 class UsersProfileTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  include ApplicationHelper

   def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
   end

  test "profile display" do
   get user_path(@user)
   assert_template 'users/show'
   assert_select 'title', full_title(@user.name)
   assert_select 'h1', text: @user.name
   assert_select 'h1>img.gravatar'
   assert_match @user.microposts.count.to_s, response.body
   assert_select 'div.pagination'
   @user.microposts.paginate(page: 1).each do |micropost|
   assert_match micropost.content, response.body
   end
 end
end
```

**test_helper**

```
 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
   require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
   require 'rails/test_help'

 class ActiveSupport::TestCase
     # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  include ApplicationHelper

   # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
   def is_logged_in?
      !session[:user_id].nil?
   end

   # Logs in a test user.
   def log_in_as(user, options = {})
      password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
      remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
   if integration_test?
       post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                  password:    password,
                                  remember_me: remember_me }
   else
       session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end

  private

    # Returns true inside an integration test.
    def integration_test?
      defined?(post_via_redirect)
    end
 end
```

Comment: current_user is nil. 
It's not enough to set @user to make current_user contain a value.

Comment: But I've already defined current_user in sessions_helper.rb.. It isn't enough?

Comment: Please show the contents of sessions_helper.rb and users_profile_test.rb

Comment: 1. It means `current_user` is `nil`. 2. `if` condition does not look good (single assignment operator) `if support = current_user.supports.find_by_micropost_id(micropost.id)`. It should be `==`.

Comment: @AhmedFathy I've already edited my question and I ve added sessions_helper.rb, users_profile_test.rb, test_helper

Comment: @HarshGupta Can you check my new added files ? Also, when I write it as " support == current_user.supports.find_by_micropost_id(micropost.id) " , I have got more errors with my first error.

Comment: things are a little messy in your code... Anyways try to call log_in_as(@user) at the beginning of the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `current_user` method is returning nil as your terminal have nil value to `session[:user_id]` and `cookies.signed[:user_id]` and thus none of the `if condition` passes. Try a `else` and give some value to `current_user`. Or else you can also use some debugging tools like `pry` to check values in season and cookies in `current_user` method.